# What is the difference between "Double" and "double" in Java?

Tags: java, double

What is the difference between `Double` and `double`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12226757/java-different-double-and-double-in-comparison?rq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13701818/why-is-int-changed-to-integer-automatically-in-java

Comment: Don't use `Double` unless you have a good reason to do so. It's error prone and needlessly slower.

Comment: You could have googled your exact title and found the answer a lot faster

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe *No* That is C#. In C#, `System.Double` *is* `double`. However, Java has a fixed set of primitive types and a *wrapper* for each primitive type.

Comment: It is 14 years old. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332012/double-vs-double-in-java

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`Double` is an object and `double` is a primitive data type.  [See this answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12226768/2498729).

> The Double class wraps a value of the primitive type double in an
>   object. An object of type Double contains a single field whose type is
>   double.

Source:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html

Comment: So when should I use `Double` and when to use `double`? Thank you

Comment: @F505 I would recommend `double` when just doing basic floating point computation. If there is a lot of string conversion needed, then I would use the class `Double`

Comment: Some thing important to note, is that a complex data-type Double can be null. I often use it when an operation could yield something else than a number, if something is not found, and a null value is required. Else, if a result is mandatory, I do prefer using a primitive double type.

Comment: @F505 I prefer `Double` if I need use of generics: i.e. `List<Double>`. Second case: type cast/conversion. Maybe also for comparison purposes it's better to take a wrapper class if we want to define precision level. doubles are not easy to compare if one calculate with doubles before. Maybe it's more convenient with Double wrapper class?