# The method currentSegment(float[]) in the type PathIterator is not applicable for the arguments (Double[])

Tags: java, eclipse, path-iterator

I am trying to read the Segments of an Path2D.Double in an java Programm and Eclips keeps telling me:

The method currentSegment(float[]) in the type PathIterator is not applicable for the arguments (Double[])

But in the interface PathIterator there are 2 Methods which seem to confuse Eclipse (or me)

```
/**
 * Returns the coordinates and type of the current path segment in
 * the iteration.
 * The return value is the path-segment type:
 * SEG_MOVETO, SEG_LINETO, SEG_QUADTO, SEG_CUBICTO, or SEG_CLOSE.
 * A float array of length 6 must be passed in and can be used to
 * store the coordinates of the point(s).
 * Each point is stored as a pair of float x,y coordinates.
 * SEG_MOVETO and SEG_LINETO types returns one point,
 * SEG_QUADTO returns two points,
 * SEG_CUBICTO returns 3 points
 * and SEG_CLOSE does not return any points.
 * @param coords an array that holds the data returned from
 * this method
 * @return the path-segment type of the current path segment.
 * @see #SEG_MOVETO
 * @see #SEG_LINETO
 * @see #SEG_QUADTO
 * @see #SEG_CUBICTO
 * @see #SEG_CLOSE
 */
public int currentSegment(float[] coords);

/**
 * Returns the coordinates and type of the current path segment in
 * the iteration.
 * The return value is the path-segment type:
 * SEG_MOVETO, SEG_LINETO, SEG_QUADTO, SEG_CUBICTO, or SEG_CLOSE.
 * A double array of length 6 must be passed in and can be used to
 * store the coordinates of the point(s).
 * Each point is stored as a pair of double x,y coordinates.
 * SEG_MOVETO and SEG_LINETO types returns one point,
 * SEG_QUADTO returns two points,
 * SEG_CUBICTO returns 3 points
 * and SEG_CLOSE does not return any points.
 * @param coords an array that holds the data returned from
 * this method
 * @return the path-segment type of the current path segment.
 * @see #SEG_MOVETO
 * @see #SEG_LINETO
 * @see #SEG_QUADTO
 * @see #SEG_CUBICTO
 * @see #SEG_CLOSE
 */
public int currentSegment(double[] coords);
```

My own Code looks like:

```
PathIterator it= ((Path2D.Double) p3d).getPathIterator(null, 2d);
  Double x, y;
  while (!it.isDone()) {
     Double coords[]= new Double[6];
     System.out.println("1");
     int art= it.currentSegment(coords);
     System.out.println("2");
     switch (art) {
     case PathIterator.SEG_MOVETO:
        movetoXY(coords[0], coords[1]);
        x= coords[0];
        y= coords[1];
        break;
     case PathIterator.SEG_LINETO:
        linetoXY(coords[0], coords[1]);
        break;
     case PathIterator.SEG_CLOSE:
        linetoXY(x, y);
        break;
     default:
        System.out.println("unbekanntes Segment " + art);
        break;
     }
     it.next();
  }
```

the Line with

```
     int art= it.currentSegment(coords);
```

is marked red, and the tooltip says:

**The method currentSegment(float[]) in the type PathIterator is not applicable for the arguments (Double[])**

There is a Method with float[] and another with double[] but with the same name
What do i miss here ?

Comment: `double != Double` ....

Comment: Sorry, reading my own QAuestion another Time did it. There is a diffrence between Double[] and double[]. so the correct line must be: **double coords[]= new double[6];**

Comment: You're missing this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20437003/difference-between-double-and-double

Answer (score 0):

Double[] and double[] are not the same type so you need to convert those types...

Java8 Streams can do that in a very sugar syntactically clear way:

only one important thing: Double is an object, so a Double[] can hold a null value... you need to check that!

```
Double[] d = { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, null };
double[] dArray = Arrays.stream(d).mapToDouble(x -> x == null ? 0.0 : x.doubleValue()).toArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(dArray));
```

if you are 100% sure that your Double[] has no null values then just do:

```
double[] dArray = Arrays.stream(d).mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).toArray();
```