# How can I use an apostrophe in an Identifier?

Tags: java

I am getting an "Invalid Character" error message for these identifiers. I think it is because of the apostrophe. How can I get them to work?

```
Double Semester’s_End;
Double Stonebinder’s_Familiar;
Double Mavinda,_Students'_Advocate;
```

Comment: You don't. There's no magic trick here. You name your variables with alphanumerics and underscores. Some languages will let you do funny quoting shenanigans to get unusual identifier names, but Java is not one of those

Comment: See the Naming section at [Java Tutorial: Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html).

Answer (score 1):

Because of the syntax definitions of the language, the only way to use an apostrophe in a java identifier is like this:

```
SemestersApostrophs_End
EndOfSemester
Semester_s_End
```

or similar, you get the idea.
I.e. in short, you can't.

Answer (score -1):

In short: **You can't**.
Use underscores to separate words if you want.

Also, in Java we use camelCase, where the first letter is small and the first letter of the next word is capitalized (unless it's a class, for which we use Regular).

Example:

```java
double semestersEnd;
double stonebinder_s_Familiar;
double mavinda_StudentsAdvocate;
```

Also, when initializing/declaring, it's `double`, not `Double` (so it's a lower case d). Use: [What is the difference between "Double" and "double" in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20437003/what-is-the-difference-between-double-and-double-in-java)

As @jarmod provided, use this link for more info: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html.

Comment: `double` and `Double` are not the same.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- yes, that's why I said that. Seeing that OP is a beginner, I assume that they wanted to do something like 0.0

Comment: But they can do that with `Double` just as easily as `double`.  Java will autobox literals, so `Double foo = 0.0;` is perfectly valid.

Comment: I don't think OP would want an object Double, I think they were going for a primitive data type. Although yes, they could do that.